# I need to add rel="nofollow" to the button provided by "views load more" module

Tags: views, navigation, theming

I need to add rel="nofollow" to the button "Load More" provided by Views Load More, but the problem is that the anchor is created in views_load_more.module (line 91) this way:

```
$li_next = theme('pager_next',
    array(
      'text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t($vars['more_button_text'])),
      'element' => $element,
      'interval' => 1,
      'parameters' => $parameters,
    )
  );
```

But I dont know how to add an attribute to that, when I print_r($li_next), it prints the link.

I have tried this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_pager_next(&$vars) {
  $vars['#path']['options'] = array('attributes'=>array('rel'=>'nofollow'));
}
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself, and I want to share it in case someone have the same problem in the future.

Just override the theme_pager_next() function in the template.php file of your theme like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_pager_next($variables) {
  $text = $variables['text'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $interval = $variables['interval'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
  $output = '';

  // If we are anywhere but the last page
  if ($pager_page_array[$element] < ($pager_total[$element] - 1)) {
    $page_new = pager_load_array($pager_page_array[$element] + $interval, $element, $pager_page_array);
    // If the next page is the last page, mark the link as such.
    if ($page_new[$element] == ($pager_total[$element] - 1)) {
      $output = theme('pager_last', array('text' => $text, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters,'attributes'=>array('rel'=>'nofollow')));
    }
    // The next page is not the last page.
    else {
      $output = theme('pager_link', array('text' => $text, 'page_new' => $page_new, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters,'attributes'=>array('rel'=>'nofollow')));
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

I've just add 'attributes'=>array('rel'=>'nofollow') to theme() function :)

Comment: That is the solution. Unfortunately, theme_pager_next() is not passing 'attributes' to theme_pager_link(). That would be great if you could create a patch for this and submit it for the module.Also consider marking your answer as Approved.